# ¿El hijo se sale del padre en react native en css?

Tags: android, css, reactjs, ios, react-native

Quiero que el hijo no salgo del padre, que se recorte en los bordes del padre sin mover la posición.
En HTML y CSS si pones un div dentro de otro y le pones un left de -50 aunque el número es negativo, el hijo se recorta en los bordes del padre, pero en react native no funciona de la misma manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

````
const {width, height}= Dimensions.get('window');
   
   return (
       <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
           <View style={Headers.two}>
               <Text style={{
                   left: 50,
                   fontSize:28,
                   color:colors.Primary00,
                   
               }}>
                   Hola 
               </Text>
           </View>
           <View style={Bobys.two}>

               <View style={{
                   backgroundColor: '#ea2565',
                   width:width*0.8,
                   height:height*0.7,
                   borderRadius:16,
                   position:'relative'
               }}>

                <LinearGradient
                colors={['#f37032','rgba(234, 37, 101, 0.6)']} style={{
                    width:width*0.8,
                    height:width*0.8,
                    borderRadius: (width*0.8)/2,
                    opacity:0.8,
                    left:-60,
                    bottom:30,
                    position:'absolute'
                }}
                start={{x:0.8, y:1}}
                end={{x:0.2, y:0}}
                > 
                </LinearGradient>

               </View>
           </View>
       </View>
   )
}

const style = StyleSheet.create({

});
export default HomeScreen;   ```
````

Answer (score 1):

Al padre se le asigna overflow:hidden y lo recorta